# Javascript interjection in URL bar not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url

I am trying to call a JavaScript interjection in the Chrome url bar:

```
javascript:alert(document.forms[0].to.value="me@email.com")
```

But all it does is bring up my google search results. I have checked that JavaScript is allowed in Chrome.

Comment: Can you provide us the code for your form?

Comment: Do you mean "injection" by any chance ?

Comment: Can you run this from the URL bar: `javascript:alert('test')`?
Also are you trying to alert a true/false if a form field = that email address? If so, turn the `=` into `==` to actually perform the comparison, because currently your code will try to actually SET the value to `me@gmail.com`, not compare it.

Also, if you're pasting that value into the address bar, Chrome automatically removes the `javascript:` part to prevent people from accidentally running malicious JS. Ensure after pasted, that you re-add the `javascript:`

Comment: I think javascript typed into the url bar has to be like `javascript:void(0);runSomeCommand();`.  Also what does your javascript do, alerts an assignment, that won't work.